# Play Framework compiles error in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, intellij-15

Mac platform, activator is 1.3.6, and use IDEA 15 CE.
I create a new Play-Java project with "activator new", and can be compiled with "activator compile".

but when I import the project into IDEA, choosing SBT, and I cannot make the project.
The error is:

```
Error:(1, 1) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(8, 24) java: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(18, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class IntegrationTest
Error:(23, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method assertTrue(boolean)
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declared junit dependency in your build.sbt as

```
val jUnitVersion = "4.11" // replace appropriately

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
// The rest of your dependencies
"junit" % "junit" % jUnitVersion % Test
)
```

and then try `sbt clean run`